# how to partition a square into arbitrary number of squares?

Tags: c++

I was wondering if there is way to split the area of square into specified number of smaller squares.
and assume the primary square has fixed size of 80*80.

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> Point;

class Square
{
Point left_down = {0, 0};
Point up_right;
public:
int lowerB(){ return left_down.first; }
int upperB() { return up_right.first; };

Square(){}
Square(int size) :up_right({size, size}) {};
Square(Point p1, Point p2): left_down(p1), up_right(p2) 
{}

static int number_of_squares;
};
int Square::number_of_squares = 1;
```

and i derived a class from Square to form the sub-squares:

```
class Sub_sqr: public Square
{
Point xy1;
Point xy2;

int S_indx; // an identifier

public:
Sub_sqr() { number_of_squares++; }
int indx() { return S_indx; }
};
```

I've tried the above algorithm, is it correct? the number of instances we make the number of squares we have.
for example if we want to extract 256 not overlapping sub-squares out of square with size 80 * 80 or whatever, we should have 256 instances of sub_sqr class.

My final goal to make grid inside the square by partitioning it into equal size sub-squares.

[Square partitioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hy8jF.jpg)

Any comments or help will be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Welcome to SO. What do you mean by creating a grid (i.e. where is this grid stored?)? Where is the algorithm you are mentioning?

Comment: Hm, at first, I don't see why the child squares need to be represented by a separate class, you should be able to reuse the parent class (at least if you give it an identifer as well). Then *if* you inherit, make the parent's points protected, so you don't need other two (redundant) ones. Finally, if I understand the problem right, it is not solvable for every number. How do you want to split your square into only two children? Or do you allow to "throw away" parts of the parent area? In this case, do you want to maximise the sum of the child square areas?

Comment: what is the purpose of xy1, xy2? You don't do anything with it. Why do you use a static number_of_squares? Why derive. You are using derivation incorrectly in the sense that one does not "derive" implementation, but rather compose it. Is a Sub_sqr a Square in the real sense, from an interface perspective? Typically when "deriving" implementation, already know that your doing something wrong. I see no algorithm

Comment: If your final goal is equal sized child squares, you further limit the numbers for which you can get a solution to square numbers (1, 4, 9, 16, ...).

Comment: Thanks for the fast responses, its not an algorithm which exists(sorry for mentioning that) i were thinking about approach for doing this and i thought this way will give me the results, i cant find any other way. about the xy1 and xy2, they are the coordinates of two corners of each sub_square.

Comment: I will add a drawing to my question to demonstrate what i mean...Regards

Comment: I used matrix to made the grid in my other question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/53019748/10566333). i really dont know what is the best option for my problem. so please guide me with this. thanks in advance